# Cannot get multiple Angular Directives for form validation to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form with two input controls, each with a different directive for validation:

```
<input name='foo' id='foo' ng-model='foobar' validate-foo>
<input name='bar' id='bar' ng-model='foobar' validate-bar>
```

Directive for foo:

```
app.directive('validateFoo', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var id= attr.id;
            if(viewValue.length > 0) {
                console.log("*** foo is not empty");
            }
            else{
                console.log("*** foo is empty");
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Directive for bar:

```
app.directive('validateBar', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var id= attr.id;
            if(viewValue.length > 0) {
                console.log("*** bar is not empty");
            }
            else{
                console.log("*** bar is empty");
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

The error I'm getting is the following when the page is rendered:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=valida
```

Can i not have multiple directives for validation in one form?

Here's my directive that does the dynamic html, the compile part...

```
html= <input name=......, etc. etc.';
var dom= angular.element(html);
$element.append(dom);
$compile(dom)($scope);
```

Comment: Same code, works fine for me.. http://plnkr.co/edit/fe9wqK?p=preview `Can i not have multiple directives for validation in one form` - Yes you can. Also when using parsers you would need to return the viewvalue as well, so that value gets assigned after parsing.

Comment: thx...i'll update Plunker to be more specific, i must be missing something

Comment: the only diff i can see is that i am dynamically generating the html from another directive. in that directive i add the different validator directives. when i just use one validator directive, all is well...would u have any idea if that would make a difference?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing in that directive. Cant guess without seeing...one basic thing is that you would need to `$compile` it..

Comment: i am compiling, and i learned to compile AFTER i 'replace'...i'll edit my question and add that directive to see if u can see anything...

Comment: I found the issue, I did not have 'ngModel' in my dynamic version, d'uh...thx for the help...why don't u provide an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Cool!. You have more context than i do. You can add answer and accept yourself when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing 'ngModel' in the dynamically generated html